# SUM and concatenation

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenation

I have the following table:

| customer1 | apple | pear | grape | orange |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

And I want a column where 1 is set if the client only has oranges and another column where a concatenation is made of the fruits they have separated by "," for example:

| customer1 | apple | pear | grape | orange | only_orange | fruits |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | apple, orange |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | pear, grape, orange |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | orange |
| 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | orange |

What I did was make a query where I would get the clients that only have oranges and I put it in a temporary table

```
SELECT [customer1] 
INTO #tmp1
FROM customer_fruits
WHERE [apple] = 0 AND [pear] = 0 AND [grape] = 0 AND [orange] = 1
```

Later I did a left join with my original table and changed the nulls to "0", obtaining the following table, although I reached the result, I don't know if there is another way but I couldn't do the concatenation part anymore.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following query

```
SELECT 
    customer1, 
    apple, 
    pear, 
    grape, 
    orange,
    CASE 
        WHEN orange = 1 AND (apple = 1 OR pear = 1 OR grape = 1) 
            THEN 0 
        WHEN orange = 1 
            THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
    END as only_orange,
    CONCAT_WS(',',
    CASE WHEN apple = 1 THEN 'apple' ELSE NULL END,
    CASE WHEN pear = 1 THEN 'pear' ELSE NULL END,
    CASE WHEN grape = 1 THEN 'grape' ELSE NULL END,
    CASE WHEN orange = 1 THEN 'orange' ELSE NULL END) as fruits
FROM 
    fruits;
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 2):

If you use reasonably new SQL Server version, `CONCAT_WS` simplifies this task:

```sql
select  *
,   orange  * (1 - SIGN(apple + pear + grape))
,   CONCAT_WS(',',CASE WHEN apple = 1 THEN 'apple' END, CASE WHEN pear = 1 THEN 'pear' END, CASE WHEN grape = 1 THEN 'grape' END, CASE WHEN orange = 1 THEN 'orange' END)
from (
    VALUES  (1, 1, 0, 0, 1)
    ,   (2, 0, 1, 1, 1)
    ,   (3, 0, 0, 0, 1)
    ,   (4, 0, 0, 0, 1)
) t (customer1,apple,pear,grape,orange)
```

For older versions, use CONCAT, but it's a bit more ugly:

```sql
select  *
,   orange  * (1 - SIGN(apple + pear + grape))
,   STUFF(CONCAT(',' + CASE WHEN apple = 1 THEN 'apple' END, ',' + CASE WHEN pear = 1 THEN 'pear' END, ',' + CASE WHEN grape = 1 THEN 'grape' END, ',' + CASE WHEN orange = 1 THEN 'orange' END), 1, 1, '')
from ...
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is an absolutely generic version.

Nothing is hard-coded outside of primary key column "ID" and column in question "orange". So, it could be many more fruits columns horizontally.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, apple BIT, pear BIT, grape BIT, orange BIT);
INSERT @tbl (apple,  pear, grape, orange) VALUES
(1, 0, 0, 1),
(0, 1, 1, 1),
(0, 0, 0, 1),
(0, 0, 0, 1);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT t.* 
    , IIF(cnt = 1 AND t.orange = 1, 1, 0) AS only_orange
    , REPLACE(x.query('for $x in /root/*[local-name()!="ID"][text()=1]
        return local-name($x)').value('text()[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)')
        , SPACE(1), ',') AS fruits
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT t.* FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT('root')) AS t1(x)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT x.value('count(/root/*[local-name()!="ID"][text()=1])', 'INT')) AS t2(cnt);
```

**Output**

| ID | apple | pear | grape | orange | only_orange | fruits |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | apple,orange |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | pear,grape,orange |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | orange |
| 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | orange |